# ActiveRecord using pluck with includes/left outer joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pluck

When I do includes it left joins the table I want to filter on, but when I add pluck that join disappears.  Is there any way to mix pluck and left join without manually typing the sql for 'left join'

Here's my case:

```
Select u.id 
From users u
Left join profiles p on u.id=p.id
Left join admin_profiles a on u.id=a.uid
Where 2 in (p.prop, a.prop, u.prop)
```

Doing this is just loading all the values:

```
Users.includes(:AdminProfiles, :Profiles).where(...).map{ |a| a[:id] }
```

But when I do pluck instead of map, it doesn't left join the profile tables.

Comment: You really should form a better question, add examples, errors, to avoid getting downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're using `includes` which doesn't really do a join, instead it fires a second query after the first one to query for the associations, in your case you want them both to be actually joined, so for that replace `includes(:something)` with `joins(:something)` and every thing should work fine.

Replying to your comment, i'm gonna quote few parts from the [rails guide about active record query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

1. From the section `Solution to N + 1 queries problem`

   ```
   clients = Client.includes(:address).limit(10)
   clients.each do |client|
     puts client.address.postcode
   end
   ```

   > The above code will execute just 2 queries, as opposed to 11 queries in the previous case:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 10
   SELECT addresses.* FROM addresses WHERE (addresses.client_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
   ```

   as you can see, two queries, no joins at all.
2. From the section `Specifying Conditions on Eager Loaded Associations` [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

   > Even though Active Record lets you specify conditions on the eager loaded associations just like joins, the recommended way is to use joins instead.

   Then an example:

   ```
   Article.includes(:comments).where(comments: { visible: true })
   ```

   > This would generate a query which contains a LEFT OUTER JOIN whereas the joins method would generate one using the INNER JOIN function instead.

   ```
   SELECT "articles"."id" AS t0_r0, ... "comments"."updated_at" AS t1_r5 FROM "articles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."article_id" = "articles"."id" WHERE (comments.visible = 1)
   ```

   > If there was no where condition, this would generate the normal set of two queries.

Comment: Includes does a left join, it doesn't fire another query. Join does a inner join, in order to make it do a left join you need to write manual sql. My question is fine.

Comment: Please see my amended question to understand why I require left joins

Comment: "Includes does a left join, it doesn't fire another query" -> `includes` tries to be smart and does either one depending on some logic.